# How do I use XCode 3.x with iOS5 sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

My current xcode is Xcode 3.2.6. It has iOS4.3. Can I use XCode 3.2.6 with iOS5 sdk. Is iOS5 sdk available as a stand alone download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, as far as I understand you would need to migrate to xcode 4 if you wish to work with iOS5